# How to unlock windows programmatically

Tags: windows, windows-7, mirror, nabaztag

I would like to make use of my old mirror (by violet) which allow to trigger events when you put and take a rfid tag on/off a rfid tag reader.
Using  [LibMirror](https://sourceforge.net/projects/libmirror/) I can program events in c# which is quite convienent.

My idea is to lock and unlock my station when I take and put the rfid tag on the mirror.

It is quite easy to lock the station thanks to [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1263217/277527), unlocking however seems more difficult.

Several posts [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6975206/unlock-windows-programmatically),[4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/174225/unlock-windows-workstation-programatically) on SO show that's difficult but I would like to have an definitive answer.

I must precise that I **am not interested** in any consideration of security, this much more for the sake of doing it.

**EDIT** : mirware from violet used to allow this, that's why I am convinced this is possible.

Any clue would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No, this is not possible.** Is that definitive enough for you?

Whether you're concerned with security or not, the Windows team *is* and absolutely *must be*. Consequently, there is no API provided to unlock a secured desktop.

It wouldn't make sense anyway—you have to enter a password in order to unlock the workstation, and how is a function call going to enter a password?

UI automation or whatever some ingenious hacker might cook up isn't going to work because the secure attention sequence (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>) is required to prevent people from doing precisely this.

The only solution would be to completely replace the Windows security system. On Windows XP, you'd do that by [writing a new GINA DLL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380543.aspx) to replace the standard `msgina.dll`. Things got slightly more complicated in Windows Vista, where [GINA was replaced with the new Credential Providers](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsvistasecurity/archive/2006/08/25/724271.aspx). You might find [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163489.aspx) useful if you're interested in pursuing such a route.

Comment: quite definitive indeed because I don't want to reimplement a custom api.

Comment: Hacks and tricks aren't going to work. I thought I made that pretty clear through the explanation of why not...