# How to write an application that unlocks windows with RFID tag

Tags: c#, windows, rfid

I need to write an application that locks a pc running windows 7. The locking is done via mouse click on a lock icon, or due to inactivity.

**What's special in my case is that the unlocking is done via one of several [RFID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio-frequency_identification) tags.**

I got the RFID reader, which simulates key presses when a tag is presented.

---

Solution?

I thought about implementing a screensaver that checks the RFID against a table of legitimate users, but I'm not sure if this is a good approach since it should not be circumvented by pressing CTRL-ALT-DELETE, ALT-Tab,....

I'm not looking for high level security here, just a way to prevent easy access to the PC.

**How would you approach that problem? Do you think the screensaver idea is the way to go?**

---

Update

From this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8816864/220636) I know that it is not possible to unlock a secured desktop (with secured I mean locked with <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>) with a RFID tag. But perhaps I could prevent access without using the windows desktop security lock...?

Comment: if you can simulate key presses, simulate `Win Key` + `L`

Comment: @HamidP: The unlocking is not done with the windows password. So I can't use the standard lock screen.

Comment: take a look at http://openkiosk.sourceforge.net/index.html

Comment: [Create Custom Login Experiences With Credential Providers For Windows Vista](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/magazine/cc163489.aspx) but C# might not be the best tool for the job.

Comment: Without knowing how all about the simulated keys.... maybe have it put the password in for you?