# Remotely initiating notepad instance as interactive process

Tags: c#, authentication

I am trying to do the following:

```
computer         computer
   A                B
   |                | Computer B is logged off 
   |--login-------->|
   |                | Computer B logs in as an interactive user
   |<------SUCESS---|
   |-Start notepad->|
   |                | Computer B shows desktop with notepad instance open.
```

Session0 isolation prevents me from showing notepad as interactive user.

I have tried a lot of solution - but none works. 
I tried getting token using WMI (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms257337(v=vs.80).aspx)
but it doesn't work.

I tried to use LogonUser function (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378184(v=vs.85).aspx) but it doesn't work.

I tried multiple solutions as suggested by this link:
[Unlock Windows workstation programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/174225/unlock-windows-workstation-programatically)
But nothing there works.

What is the way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that it is not possible to fully impersonate an interactive user programatically, such that you get a physical console and associated GDI constructs.

It appears that the only way to do this is to enable auto-logon to an interactive session, and refactor the service to speak to a new client component in the interactive session. To address the security disadvantage of this, Microsoft recommends implementing a shell replacement to place the server in a "Kiosk" mode on logon (i.e. no Explorer access without appropriate credentials).

I went though the windows 7 SDK "session 0 isolation" issue. The tutorial say we should use the CreateProcessAsUser function to create a process in the requesting user’s desktop. I tried the offered solution but we need to be logged in as the user specified in the CreateProcessAsUser call in order to see the process interactively.

Answer (score 0):

You should create an `agent application` which is started automatically at user login.
Dropping a shortcut to the application's exe file in the `Startup` folder under the `All Users` folder should suffice.

This application should connect to your Windows Service and await commands.

You could make the 2 processes communicate via `Names Pipes` and `.NET Remoting`.

You will end up with 2 applications which total N + 1 running processes. 1 main service and 1 agent for each interactive session.

Comment: You missed a point: I want notepad to appear as an interactive process.
This solution suggests that the computer must be in interactive mode (logged in, or showing it's desktop) in order to work. If I start the notepad instance it won't show anything on the desktop.

Comment: "This solution suggests that the computer must be in interactive mode" --- if that were not true, how would you want "notepad to appear as an interactive process" ?

Comment: programatically log in on computer B, when it shows the desktop tell computer B to start notepad under logged in user. (see sequence diagram in my question)