# Windows Log in using cmd line

Tags: java, windows, batch-file, cmd

I am wondering if is it possible to log in using cmd line, I presume this will include providing security credentials? I know there is a cmd line argument to lock a pc "rundll32.exe user32.dll,LockWorkStation" but if there was an "unlock" command?

The question has been asked before but never fully answered ,I do not wish to use existing frameworks ,i wish to use cmd line if possible

Comment: Not sure, and this may sound silly (but logical to me); wouldn't the opposite be Unlock?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unlock Windows workstation programatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/174225/unlock-windows-workstation-programatically)